# print a one dictionary at a time to a table from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I want to print only Tom's recode to a table without using function

```
fe=[{"Name": "Tom", "age": 10,"group":"sdd","points":2,},
    {"Name": "Mark", "age": 5,"group":"sdo","points":6,},
    {"Name": "Pam", "age": 7,"group":"spp","points":4,}],

dashes = "{:<20} + {:<8} + {:^14} + {:^11} \n".format("-"*20, "-"*8, "-"*10, "-"*14, "-"*11)
info ="{:<20} | {:<8} | {:^14} | {:^11}\n".format("Name", "age", "group","points")
info+=dashes    
value=0
fe[value]
info+="{:<20} | {:<8} | {:^14} | {:^11} \n".format(value["Name"],value["age"],value["group"],value["points"])
info+=dashes
print(info)
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to assign `fe[value]` to a variable

Comment: please see https://pypi.org/project/terminaltables/

Answer (score 0):

`value` is `0`.

```py
value = fe[0]
info += "{:<20} | {:<8} | {:^14} | {:^11} \n".format(value["Name"],value["age"],value["group"],value["points"])
```